# Union of two tables with information of the origin of each row

Tags: sql, case, union, full-outer-join

suppose I have two tables `A` and `B`, both with only 1 column `name`. Some rows appear in both tables while some are exclusive to one table. I want to union these two tables together into a table `C` that has 3 columns `name`, `is_in_A` and `is_in_B`. For a row that appeared in both `A` and `B`, the last 2 fields would both be 'true'. For a row that appeared in only `A`, only `is_in_A` would be 'true' and `is_in_B` would be false.

My current solution works like this:
Create three temporary tables that all have the columns `name`, `is_in_A` and `is_in_B`:

- `A_join_B` that has all rows that are in `A` and `B`. `is_in_A` and `is_in_B` are both true for every row in this table
- `A_minus_B` that has all rows that are exclusive to `A`. `is_in_A` is true and `is_in_B` is false for every row in that table.
- `B_minus_A` respectively.

Now I union all 3 tables together to get my result.

Is there a better/easier way to do this (ideally as a single union without any temporary tables)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `FULL` join of the tables:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.name, b.name) AS name,
       CASE WHEN a.name IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END AS is_in_A,
       CASE WHEN b.name IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END AS is_in_B
FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN b
ON b.name = a.name
```

If your database does not support boolean values like `true` and `false`, change to `1` and `0` or string literals `'true'` and `'false'`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=702094c97af48761ab23e9aecbffa2e4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select name, sum(in_a), sum(in_b)
from ((select name, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
       from a
      ) union all
      (select name, 0, 1
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by name;
```